# How may I get the Explorer left pane to show folder shortcuts

Tags: windows-7

Though here the Explorer left pane shows folders, it doesn't show folder shortcuts.

[image]

Anyone know a remedy?

Comment: It is not possible. A shortcut is a file **not** a folder.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't see the navigation pane on the left side of an open window, click **Organize**, point to **Layout**, and then click **Navigation** pane to display it.

[image]

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. He already has a navigation pane as shown in the image in the question. He asking how to show folder shortcuts in the navigation pane.